# How to remove/hide the resize button in jqGrid (JQuery)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

How to remove/hide the resize option in jqGrid (JQuery)?

```
var grid = $("#list");    
grid.jqGrid({
                    datatype: 'local',
                    data: mydata,
                    colModel: cm,
                    rowNum: 10,
                    rowList: [10, 25, 50],
                    pager: '#pager',
                    gridview: true,
                    rownumbers: false,
                    viewrecords: true,
                    hidegrid: false,
                    autowidth: true,
                    caption: 'Examples',
                    height: '100%' 
                });

grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false });
```

[image]

Check the right bottom corner of the image. That is the resize option i am asking about.

Comment: could you provide you jqGrid code?

Comment: There are no "resize option" or "resize button" in jqGrid. What you mean? Do you probably mean the show/hide grid button, which appears on the right side of the Caption layer? Do you use `gridResize` method? Or you mean resizing of columns?

Comment: If you mean the column resizing you can specify `resize:false` in the colModel attributes - [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code which you currently posted don't produce the resizable area at the right, bottom of the grid. If you do have the area you have called [gridResize](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajquery_ui_methods#resizable_grid) method *explicitly* somewhere in your code.

So you should examine your code for the call of [gridResize](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajquery_ui_methods#resizable_grid) method and remove it.

Comment: Yes, I have used this method. I think, I misunderstood the gridResize method and used improperly. Thanks Oleg.

Answer (score 0):

As I have seen that someone said, you should specify the option resizable to false in colMedl and that foreach col, like:

```
...colModel:[{resizable:false,}]...
```